# recover the inaccessible class c++

Tags: c++

Next code:

```
//plan.hpp class plan{
        public:
          plan(int bx,int by):x(bx),y(by){ }
          int x;
         int y; };

class flower:plan{
    public:
       flower(int ax,int ay):plan(ax,ay){}
 };


//base.hpp
 include plan.hpp
 include <vector>

 class vec{ std::vector<plan> plants;
 plants.push_back(flower(x,y));
```

gnu compiler says: 103  54  C:\Users\sonera\Desktop\osku\koodaus\c++\ohjelmat\FOREST\simulaattor.hpp    [Error] 'plan' is an inaccessible base of 'flower'

Comment: 1) You probably wanted `public` inheritance, for classes, the default is `private` inheritance. 2) Inserting an object of a derived class into a vector of base class elements will *slice* the object inserted. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Your code snippet cannot compile and it's hard to distinguish the errors you've inserted accidentally in the transcription from the errors you have in your actual code.

Comment: What's `class flower::plan`?

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
class flower: public plan{
    public:
       flower(int ax,int ay):plan(ax,ay){}
};
```

`::` operator means access resolution operator - rightfully said by the compiler that `plan` does not exist in `flower`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote local includes and add a hash in front of each one:

```
#include "plan.hpp"
#include <vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that your typo with two colons in class definition of flower

class flower **::** plan{

is the reason of the error message.

It seems that the reason of the error message is that you try to access private data members or member functions of class plan in methods of class flower.

The problem is that when you explicitly do not specify access control as for example

class flower : **public** plan{

then by default for classes inheritance of the base class is private. That is the following definition of the class

class flower : plan{

is equivalent to

class flower : **private** plan{

That means that inside class flower you may access only public members of subobject/class plan.

Maybe you did not want the private inheritance and made it by mistake. In this case write

class flower : **public** plan{

Or use keyword struct instead of class. For structures inheritance by default is public.